# typescipt and react searchbar api fetch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I'm trying to fetch the author's name in this search bar component. the idea is to fetch the author's name in the search bar and display the author's picture with the author's name. but it's not working for me. Can someone help and explain why this is not working. Thank you.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./Searchbar.css";

import axios from "axios";


function Searchbar() {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://picsum.photos/v2/?=${query}`);
            setData(res.data);
        };
        if (query.length === 0 || query.length > 2) fetchData();
    }, [query]);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <input
                className="search"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />
            <div>{data}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Searchbar;
```

Comment: Could you describe what's not working exactly - is the API not sending you data back, are you getting console errors, is nothing changing in your state?

Comment: I'm not able to get data back from API, I want to make a search function where I can type the first 2 or 3 letters of authors' names and display their pictures on my layout page. here is the netlify link where you can see the Searchbar function is not  working.https://photosearch007.netlify.app/

Comment: I posted an answer but this is an API problem - if you go to picsum.photos, they don't have a way to let you search for the authors. They only have a /list endpoint where you can fetch all the authors.

Comment: Unless you own the API, you can't change that behavior.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to do the filtering client side in a separate piece of state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is wrong.

```
`https://picsum.photos/v2/?=${query}`
```

This goes to a bad page. Can you go to picsum.photos and use their available API endpoints accordingly, such as their list endpoint.

`https://picsum.photos/v2/list`

It looks like there's only a limited number of authors currently so you could fetch it, and store the authors array in `data` and then handle the searching separately.

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

// Add one more state to store the authors being searched for
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list`);
            setData(res.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

// Query that handles searching
useEffect(() => {
  setSearchResults(data.filter((authorData) => authorData['author'].toLowerCase().includes(query)));
}, [query, data]);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <input
                className="search"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />
            <div>{searchResults}</div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Just missing a bracket, updated.

Comment: Also please note I updated the first useEffect - since we no longer use query, I removed it from the deps array otherwise both useEffects would trigger and data would keep being fetched

Comment: Property 'author' does not exist on type 'never'.    const query: string
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setSearchResults' needs the current value of 'data'.

Comment: Made a couple of edits

Comment: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: Here's a codesandbox showing the solution working: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-tdd-i4gnxw?file=/src/index.tsx